# Variable I did not make is coming up in the console p5

Tags: p5.js

I've had this error message "TypeError: a is undefined" for a while and I finally narrowed it down to a few lines of code in my project. I've created a smaller project from the original to demonstrate my problem:

```
new p5();
var particle = function(X, Y, C, Kind, Fun) {
        this.pos = createVector(X, Y);
        this.vel = createVector(0, 0);
        this.accel = createVector(0, 0);
        this.col = C;
        this.isDead = false;
        this.kind = Kind;
        this.affect = Fun;
};

function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
};

var particles = new Array(new particle(1, 1, color(1, 1, 1), function () {
    cosole.log("your mamma");
}));

function draw() {

};
```

If I run this in a browser, I get the error message mentioned above. In case you were wondering what my html looks like, here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="p5_test.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    body {margin: none; padding: none;}
</style>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Another thing is that you **cannot** access p5 functions in global scope, it needs to be inside a p5 construct like `draw` or `setup`. In this case, you **cannot** use `color(1, 1, 1)` outside `draw` or `setup`.

Comment: @MasterYushi Notice the `new p5()` at the top of the sketch. This should allow P5 functions to be called before `setup()` is called. See [the wiki](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-cant-i-assign-variables-using-p5-functions-and-variables-before-setup) for more info.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yes, thanks, however the issue in this snippet, *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_colorMode' of undefined* is due to `color()` being called in global scope. See this [issue.](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1293)

Comment: @MasterYushi Yeah I understand. Check out my answer below :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use on-demand global mode to get around the restriction of not being able to use P5 functions until after `setup()` is called. I would expect your code to work.

However, when I run the code, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_colorMode' of undefined
    at new p5.Color (p5.js:6482)
    at p5.color (p5.js:6174)
    at sketch.js:17
```

You're using the minified version of the library, so variable names aren't really useful. I'm using the unminified version, so I can see that the actual problem is that the `_colorMode` variable can't be found.

Tracing through the code, we see that your code calls the `color()` function, which hits line 6174 of P5.js:

```
return new p5.Color(this._renderer, arguments);
```

Which calls the `p5.Color` constructor, which hits line 6482 of P5.js:

```
this.mode = renderer._colorMode;
```

From this, we can see that the `renderer` variable is undefined, and when we try to access its `_colorMode` variable, we get the error.

So, it looks like P5's internal `renderer` variable is not defined, even though you're using on-demand global mode. The on-demand global mode gives you access to simple functions like `random()`, but it doesn't give you access to functions that require a renderer to have been initialized.

To fix your problem, just move your initialization into your `setup()` function:

```
var particle = function(C) {
        this.col = C;
};

var particle;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    particle = new particle(color(1, 1, 1));
}

function draw() {

}
```

Note that you can also get rid of the `new p5()` at the top of your code, since it wasn't really helping you at all. Also note that I've simplified your code for the purpose of creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the same ideas should hold true for your main project.

Comment: very nicely explained (+1)

Comment: +1 for in-depth explanation, something that I ignored and just wen't with -*you shouldn't do this, end of story*. However, as the OP has described, his console shows up *`a is not defined`* and not the error we were talking about :p

Comment: @MasterYushi That's because OP is using the minified version of the library, so variable names are shortened. The `_colorMode` variable becomes `a`, for example.

Comment: That's a very clean and understandable answer. I also learned that I should probably use the unminified version when debugging in the future.

Comment: @CalebBertrand Thanks. And yeah, I would go so far as to say that unless you have a good reason to use the minified version, you should just use the unminified version anyway.